# Is this correct to assign value to string out of its allocated size in c++?

Tags: c++, string

```
char *str;
str = new char[1];
str[0]='1';
str[1]='2';
str[2]='>';
str[3]='\0';
```

This is what I want to do. Is it correct to assign values out of its allocated range.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is it correct to assign values out of its allocated range.

No. Doing so has undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

Two alternatives:

Appending to a string:

```
std::string s;
s += '1';
s += '2';
s += '>';
// s += '\0'; // not necessary as this is tracked for you
```

Using std::string's fill constructor if you want to specify a size:

```
std::string s(3, ' ');
s[0] = '1';
s[1] = '2';
s[2] = '>';
```